# Changing variable of a function

Tags: equation-solving

How can i invert a function like

$$y(x)=a \cdot e^x$$
and put it in the form of
$$x(y)= ...$$

Comment: There is the command `InverseFunction` check it out!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot quite, because you are using the symbol `y` to denote a function and a variable.  But other than that, you can proceed in multiple ways.

Following the suggestion of @Buddha_the_Scientist, you could do this:

```
ClearAll[f, finv, x, y]
f = Function[x, a Exp[x]]
finv = InverseFunction[f]
```

If you care about the name of the formal parameter, you can replace it:

```
finv /. {x -> y}
```

Alternatively, you may be thinking of a relationship between two variables, `x` and `y`.  Then you may use `Solve` or `Reduce`:

```
(* using Solve *)
solns = Simplify[Solve[y == a Exp[x], x, Reals], a > 0 && y > 0]
x == (x /. First@solns)
(* using Reduce *)
Last@Reduce[y == a Exp[x] && a > 0 && y > 0, x, Reals]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Just take the `Log` of both sides and solve for `x`.

A rule to simplify with later:

```
logsimp = {n_ Log[x_] -> Log[x^n], Log[x_] - Log[y_] -> Log[x/y], 
  Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[x y], Log[1/x_] -> -Log[x]};
```

Your equation for `y[x]`

```
eq = y == a E^x;

Log[eq[[1]]] == Log[eq[[2]]] // PowerExpand
(*Log[y] == Log[a] + x*)

Solve[%, x] // Flatten
(*{x -> Log[y] - Log[a]}*)

x[y] == (x /. % /. logsimp)
(*x[y] == Log[y/a]*)
```

Of course if you actually wanted to use it in a calculation you would declare `x[y_]=` instead of `x[y] ==`.  Might have to be a little trickier of using negative `a`.